# Doit-on écrire « et », « hé », « eh », ou…?

Tags: orthographe, oral, onomatopées

Une question que je me pose souvent en transcrivant par écrit du langage parlé, doit-on écrire :

- Et
- Hé
- Eh
- … ?

Il y a différents contextes possibles, peut-être que ces différentes orthographes sont toutes valides à un moment ?

Comment: Ma question manque un peu d'exemples... Je pense à des formules comme "et bien" notamment, ou "hé hé"

Comment: *Et* a un sens bien précis, alors que *Hé* et *Eh* sont des onomatopées. Il est difficile de trancher. Dans une transcription d'oral, c'est le son produit et le contexte qui doivent aider à déterminer la manière d'écrire.

Comment: @StéphanePéchard: *[Eh](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/Eh)* a six sens pour le dictionnaire de l'Académie, par exemple le sens 2. est « Exprime la surprise, parfois aussi l'admiration ou l'indignation ». C'est à peu près la même chose pour *hé*. Peu de choses sont insensées en Français.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

D'après le dictionnaire de l'Académie, l'interjection en question peut s'écrire [hé](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/h%C3%A9) ou [eh](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/eh), il est toutefois précisé que *hé bien* est archaïque et remplacé par *eh bien*. 
En revanche, [et](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/et) en début de phrase a un autre sens,

> Placé en tête de phrase ou de proposition, et anime le discours, constitue une relance, ou introduit quelque solennité (style biblique ou épique).

Answer (score 5):

Les trois sont corrects, selon le contexte :

- "et" s'emploie uniquement pour indiquer l'addition ;
- "hé" s'emploie comme une interjection, par exemple : "Hé bé!" ;
- "eh" s'emploie également comme une interjection, par exemple : "Eh bien".

En général, je me souviens des cas d'utilisation de "hé" et "eh" par leur sonorité ("eh" se prononçant comme "è").

Comment: Regarde le sens 2 pour [et](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/et).

Comment: @Evpok: Intéressant. Pour le style biblique, je pense que c'est particulièrement un emprunt au style hébraïque, qui utilise fortement "et" (v) pour indiquer un lien de causalité ou de successivité entre les phrases.

Comment: @Raphnk Comme *Now* en anglais?

Comment: @Evpok: Oui, les traductions anglaises comme la King James rendent souvent le "v" par *now*.

Comment: C'est toujours biblique le _et_ en début de phrase? Et dire que je l'ignorais...